# php: array search - partial needle

Tags: php

I'm searching for a needle who's key value is an array with a key 'id' and value 8. In other words I only have the partial value of the needle, part of an array, and I would like to find the key whose value is is an array that has a key 'id' and corresponding value 8, all other key value pairs notwithstanding, as in they don't matter diddly squat.

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: Explain More ! it is a simple array or an array of arrays ? 
the id refers to an array or to a value ? can you post the structure of the array !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
//use array("key_name" => array("id" => 8)); for PHP versions older than 5.4
$arr = ["key_name"=>['id' => 8, 'other' => "random value"]]; 

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($value['id']) && $value['id'] == 8) {
        echo "Found array value with id=>8\n";
        echo "Key: $key\n"; //prints "key_name"
    }
}
```

This code simply iterates through your key/value pairs, until it finds an value that is an array and contains `['id' => 8]` and prints out the corresponding key.